# How to access HashMap data from a Public/private Class

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i am passing an image via arguments from an activity to a dialogbox IMageview. However, when the image appears in the dialog's image view it is blurry and very bad quality.
Please see code below:

My onclick listener in my activity:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                //String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                //int img = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.event_pic)).getId();
                ImageView img = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.event_pic));

                img.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();
                String txt =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle_single)).getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                confirmEvent(txt, bitmap);
            }
        });
```

MY confirmEvent :

```
public void confirmEvent(CharSequence text, Bitmap id) {
        DialogFragment mDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence("text", text);
        args.putParcelable("id", id);

        mDialog.setArguments(args);
        mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
    }
```

i suspect that is because when it reaches the imageview it is already compressed and formatted for that imageview. I know i am suppose to get the image path instead of the image from the image view but i am not sure of the correct syntax. since the image is json parsed from a website and stored in a harshMap:

my HashMap(relavant code):

```
/** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {
....

// Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("event_img",tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
            return hmBitmap;
```

What is the correct syntax in accessing this hmBitmap Object so that i could use the "event_img"?

Comment: Just a question. Are you using this task to fetch the image you are going to display?

Comment: yes, though keep in mind, i did not paste all the code, just the relavant part.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was adding this to my `onClickListener`:

```
HashMap<String, Object> currentimg = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
                String imgURI = currentimg.get("event_img").toString();
```

Apparently, my `HashMap` was already public, and with a little reading and research, I learned about how to implement `HashMap`'s.

You can also toast the `imgURI` string to verify what the `Map` contains.

Comment: It still is not clear enough what you were trying to achieve. If what you told me is true, and you are fetching images through that task, then you should not temper with the resource until is done (onPostExecute) as it's dealing with UI components and doInBackground is outside the main thread. If it's something you are displaying in the ListView, then cache and start a separate task for each image. Remember that resources are destroyed when orientation changes.

Comment: the image is being cached, i didnt show that part of the code, will have to put it when i get the time. but what i was tryin to achieve was to display an image that is present in my list view item and display it in a dialog box when the list view item is clicked. i didnt know how to retrieve that image without it being badly disfigured and burry, so i was trying to get it from the hashmap that stores the local uri( since it is stored in cache) of the image.